# returning an object from an android ViewModel to the fragment from a callback function

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, callback, android-viewmodel

I am using `ViewModel` in android to obtain an object and then pass it to a fragment to update UI components. I am trying to obtain the value of the object asynchronously and then pass the object to the fragment from the callback function. I already have a non-null value of the object in the callback and in the asynchronous task. I just am having trouble sending the object to the fragment by calling the function in the fragment java code. Here's the code snippet

Code snippet of the `ViewModel`

*EventViewModel.java*

```
class EventViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

  private OnEventListener mListener;
  Obj obj;

  //setting the listener
  public void registerOnEventListener(OnEventListener mListener){
    this.mListener = mListener;
  }

  public void getObj(){

     new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          //code to obtain non-null value of object
          //& obtains non-null value here
          obj = some-non-null-value

          if(mListener != null){
                //invoke the callback
                mListener.onEvent();
          }
        }
      });
  }

   interface OnEventListener(){
     Obj onEvent();
   }

   class A implements  OnEventListener {

     @Override
     public Obj onEvent() {

       System.out.println(obj.property1); //obj is non-null here

       //....
       return obj;
   }

 }
}
```

Code snippet of the `fragment` to which I want to send the object

*EventFragment.java*

```
public class EventFragment extends Fragment {

 private EventViewModel vm;

 @Override
 public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    vm = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(EventViewModel.class);

    EventViewModel.OnEventListener mListener = vm. new A();
    vm.registerOnEventListener(mListener);
    vm.getObj();
    Obj o = mListener.getEvent()  //shows error as 'Incompatible Types'
                                  //so o is also null   
   }
}
```

Now I know that I cannot return `obj` directly in the `getObj()` method, it gets returned before `obj` is given a non-null value, i.e. before the asynchronous task is over. On trying the above method, object o in the `EventFragment` remains null always. So, please tell a way to send the object to the fragment `EventFragment.java`. Please point if I need to post any more code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not have your `ViewModel` hold a `MutableLiveData<Obj>`, have the fragment `observe()` that `LiveData`, and then update that `MutableLiveData` from your background thread?

Comment: because the method I am trying to obtain the object has return type as `Object` and I am unable to convert it into `MutableLiveData<Obj>`

Comment: You don't "convert" it. You call `postValue()` on a `MutableLiveData<Obj>` to publish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LiveData`:

```
class EventViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
  private MutableLiveData<Obj> liveObjects = new MutableLiveData<>();

  LiveData<Obj> getObjects() {
    return liveObjects;
  }

  public void loadObject(){
     new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          Obj object = // TODO get the value

          liveObjects.postValue(object);
        }
      }).start();
  }
}

public class EventFragment extends Fragment {

 private EventViewModel vm;

 @Override
 public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    vm = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(EventViewModel.class);

    vm.getObjects().observe(this, new Observer<Obj>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable final Obj newValue) {
            // TODO something useful
        }
    });
}
```

Then, when appropriate, call `loadObject()` on the `EventViewModel` to trigger the background work and delivery of the new object.

Comment: `loadObject()` has to be called before setting the `Observer` because I get a `NullPointerException` because I am trying to invoke `Observer` to _observe_ a null value.  When should `loadObject()` be called

Comment: @aQwusjargon: "I am trying to invoke Observer to observe a null value" -- no, you need to handle a `null` value, such as via `if (newValue != null) { // TODO something useful }`.

Comment: we can check `(newValue != null)` only if we are able to observe `newValue` but my app crashes as soon as it starts, showing a `NullPointerExcpetion` which is the code is trying to observe a null value, since `getObjects()` is null before calling `loadObject()` and by the time I obtain a non-null value through `loadObject()`, `getObjects()` is called for _observing_. Will `getObjects()` have to be called asynchronously?

Comment: @aQwusjargon: "since getObjects() is null" -- sorry, I forgot to initialize the `liveObjects` field in my sample code. See the updated code.

Comment: I am printing two separate commands to the console depending on the null or null-value of the `obj` but presently none of the two commands is being printed to the console. I am calling `loadObject()` as 
    `public EventViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        loadObject();
    }`  in the`EventViewModel` class.

Comment: @aQwusjargon: I cannot help you debug your code. My point is that `LiveData` is Google's recommended choice for the sort of thing that you are trying to do, to avoid having a viewmodel directly hold listeners from the activity/fragment.

Comment: Well, there was just a teeny-weeny error, we just forgot to start the `thread` :p. Thanks, the code works!! Using `LiveData` is a very light solution and a good work around the `callbacks` which is quite easy to use in js but apparently not so much in this case.